# Is there a possibility to negotiate for reversal of charges levied on our savings account with a bank in India?

Tags: india, banking, bank-account

Does Reserve Bank of India regulate any of the charges levied by either Private or Public sector banks on our Savings accounts?

If so, is there a possibility for us to negotiate for the reversal is such charges for facilities which are not provided.

Why are there no rules that favor account holders?

Are there no such rules that the banks have to abide to when levy charges?

Why should a bank account holder have to run around bank and branches for a mistake from the bank?

Answer (score 1):

Banks need to provide a free mechanism to deposit and withdrawal money.

Banks are free to charge fees as long as it is well published.

If you are not happy with services you can complain to Banking ombudsman.